# Increasing variable by 1 every time the frame is active with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

This is properly an easy question to answer for some, hehe: How can I increase a varible value by 1 every time it enters that spesific frame?

I curently have this code which runs one time and then it will not run again next time the timeline is on the frame:

```
// This is at the end of the animation

var DAY = 0;

DAY++;
dayTextField.text = DAY;

gotoAndStop(7); // Go to the beginning and re-loop the animation
```

I have tried to do this code in a function that run from a `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function)`, but this just increased the value non-stop over and over again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some wierd reason I got it to work. This code is added in the beginning and not at the end as I did last time. Here is what I did:

```
var DAY = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newDayFunc);

function newDayFunc(event:Event) {
    if (currentFrame == 1286) {
        if (Moon.hitTestObject(wallNewDay)) {
            DAY++;
            dayTextField.text = DAY;
            trace("What day it is:", DAY);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is what I ended up using after figuring something out, hehe:

```
// I figured it out. This is on the last frame.

// Variables
var DAY = 0;
//
// Listeners
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newDayFunc);
//
// Functions
function newDayFunc(event:Event) {
        if (DAY < 7)) {
            DAY++;
            dayTextField.text = DAY;
            trace("What day it is:", DAY);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newDayFunc);
        } else {
            // Added other eventListeners that needed to be removed
            gotoAndStop("finished"); // The name of the finish frame
        }
}
//
```

Comment: Apparently you are checking the wrong object's `currentFrame` property. You are interested in day-and-night display, and you are checking `stage` instead. Try adding the listener to the MC that has a long timeline and is displaying daytime instead of stage, should do. (telepath hat off)

Comment: Thank you. I figured something funny out; I forgot to remove the ENTER_FRAME event, so it ran "forever", hehe. (I am new to ActionScript) I will update the code to show what I nice (mean). :)